# Python Summing Neg Values using While Loop

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code using `while` loop to sum all the negative numbers in a list. I am getting -10 instead of -17. Any idea why? Thanks!

```
# sum all the negative numbers using a while loop
given_list3 = [7, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, -2, -3, -5 ,-7]
total6 = 0
i = 0
while -1 < 0:
        total6 += given_list3[i]
        i += -1
        if given_list3[i] > 0:
            break
print(total6)
```

Answer (score 4):

Various thing wrong

- the `-1 < 0` does not make sense, it wont terminate
- you `break` when you find the first negative element

You should do something like

```
index = 0

while index < len(lst):
    value = lst[index]

    if value > 0:
        continue

    total += value

    index += 1
```

Note that, in python, it's more common to iterate over the values directly

```
for value in lst:
    if value >= 0:
        total += value
```

or use a *list comprehension*

```
total = sum([x for x in lst if x >= 0])
```

Comment: my whole point was trying to work with a while loop.  I know there are likely better methods to get to the end result.   However, i wanted it to break the loop whenever it finds the 1st positive element, not negative.  I believe it does that?  Thanks.

Comment: continue doesn't work plus I don't understand why I'd use that...  How do I break the loop without telling it to "break"?

Comment: if you break the loop, you lose all negative values that follow. try list `[1, -10, -10]`, it would give 0

Comment: doesn't make sense.  My code starts with -7 and adds up all negative numbers til it hits 1.  Since 1 is positive, the loop breaks and the script ends.  = -17.  It works this way.  Also, given your list it works as well as the result is -20..

Answer (score 1):

You should put a [debugger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) and step through each line that is executed. You will see that the first value added is the `numbers[0]`, which is the positive number `7`. From there on, it just works like you expect it to; it loops back and adds the numbers till it finds a positive number and then exits.

---

You can use [higher order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) like `filter` and `sum` to make your code more elegant and less error prone.

```
numbers = [7, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, -2, -3, -5 ,-7]

sum(filter(lambda x: x<0, numbers))
```

Comment: i like the debugger idea so i can see what happens with each line.  thnks for the response.

Comment: That is our main tool :-)

Comment: thnks.  I've been using Jupyter to write code so i'll have to find the debugger option.

Comment: You can do it using `import pdb; pdb.set_trace`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code innstead,

```
  l=[1,2,3,-1,-4]
  i=-1
  total=0
  while l[i]<0:
      total+=l[i]
      i-=1
  print(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
c_list = [5, 3, 1, -2, -4, -6, -100]
total6 = 0
i = 0
while c_list[i] <= len(c_list):
    for i in c_list:
        if i <= 0:
            total6 += i
            i += 1
    break
print(total6)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xh47a.png)

Answer (score 0):

To be honest this isn't the best way to write this, however if you have a sorted list where all the negative numbers are on one side than this will work.

This issue is that you set i equal to 0, which would be 7 in that list. So what your while loop is doing is, 7 + -7 + -5 + -3 + -2... You will likely want to start i = -1 so that the first object it adds is -7 which will give you your desired results.

```
# sum all the negative numbers using a while loop
given_list3 = [7, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, -2, -3, -5 ,-7]
total6 = 0
i = -1
while -1 < 0:
    total6 += given_list3[i]
    i += -1
    if given_list3[i] > 0:
        break
print(total6)
```

To explain why this works you need to understand the positioning in a list or array. Given your list:

```
List items:  [7, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, -2, -3, -5 ,-7]
Positions:   [0][1][2][3][4][5] [6] [7] [8] [9]

List items:  [  7,  5,  4,  4,  3,  1, -2, -3, -5 ,-7]
From Reverse:[-10][-9][-8][-7][-6][-5][-4][-3][-2][-1]
```

If you want to look at it you can see it this way as a continuous spectrum:

```
List:     [   7,  5,  4,  4,  3,  1, -2, -3, -5 ,-7, 7, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, -2, -3, -5 ,-7]
Positions:[ -10][-9][-8][-7][-6][-5][-4][-3][-2][-1][0][1][2][3][4][5] [6] [7] [8] [9]
```

While your list only contains 7,..-7, the call to "given_list3" operates on the above spectrum. Allowing negative numbers to work from the right while 0 and higher work from the left.

Comment: Thanks-- So when I set i = -1 does that mean the 1st object this loop looks at is going to be the last number in the list?  Versus 0 = 1st number right?

Comment: Just expanded on my answer here, that would be a correct statement.

Comment: Interesting.  So i just updated my code and made i = 9.  That worked the same as when i did i = -1.  I didn't realize i was writing it from a reverse angle.  Logically, using i = 9 makes more sense to me.  Thanks for the well thought out and clear response.

Comment: Starting from the reverse isn't a bad idea, it's use case is if you have a sorted list of unknown length and you don't want to waste a line determining how long the list is. Otherwise you need to know the length of the list before you can run it.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll have a List wherein the negative values are scattered it might be best to loop through every single object, compare if it's < 0 and then add it to your total.

```
given_list = [-2,-3,5,7,4,-5,4,3,1,-7]
total = 0
for num in given_list:
    if num < 0:
        total = total + num
print(total)
```

In this case, you won't have to worry about starting on the other side of the list.

Answer (score -1):

Assume that `given_list` is always in the the decreasing order.

```
given_list = [7, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, -2, -3, -5, -7] # find the sum of negative numbers

total = 0
# i start at the end of the list and went backward
i = len(given_list)-1
while given_list[i] < 0:
    total = total + given_list[i]
    i = i-1
print(total)
```